# CS50 pset04 - handles lack of forensic image - segmentation fault

Tags: c, image, segmentation-fault, cs50

##### Problem

The program is supposed to recover images from a memory chunk with the following requirements:

- each JPEG file start with a distinct header
- all first 3 bytes in JPEG files are the same : 0xff - 0xd8 - 0xff
- the fourth byte : 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, ...., or 0xef
- the JPEG files are stored back to back in the memory car
- each block is 512 bytes

It's compiled and runs smoothly on my local machine. But fail when I use check50. Anybody has an idea why? Please help
:( handles lack of forensic image // failed to execute program due to segmentation fault

##### Code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define FAT 512
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // program must accept only one argument
    if (argc > 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover [image disk]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open forentic file
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        fclose(input);
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    // create a buffer
    BYTE buffer[FAT];
    int fcount = -1;
    char pic_name[8];
    FILE *output;

    while (fread(buffer, FAT, 1, input))
    {
        // check if the buffer started with the 04 signed digits of jpeg
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff &&
            buffer[1] == 0xd8 &&
            buffer[2] == 0xff &&
            (buffer[3] & 0xe0) == 0xe0)
        {
            // if it's not the first picture, we need to close the connection
            // to create a new image.
            if (fcount > -1)
            {
                fclose(output);
            }
            fcount++;
            sprintf(pic_name, "%03i.jpg", fcount);
            output = fopen(pic_name, "w");
            if (output == NULL)
            {
                fclose(input);
                printf("Could not create %s.\n", pic_name);
                return 3;
            }
        }
        if (fcount > -1)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, FAT, 1, output);
        }
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (argc > 2)` should be `if (argc != 2)` since the program requires exactly one argument, neither more nor less.

Comment: How many files do you need to create ? Your pic_name var can only work from 0 to 9 because it can contains only 8 char (including \0)

Comment: @PtitXav AFAIR the CS50 test provides 50 files. But that is no problem as the filename can hold file number up to 999: `"999.jpg"` is 7 printable characters + 0 byte

Comment: Ok , my mistake

Comment: One thing I do not understand is that you do not write the first read packet. Also what is the meaning of the 4th char of each buffer : just an index or other things ? Does the first 4 char needs to be written in jpeg ?

Comment: @PtitXav The `fwrite` at the end of the `while` loop writes all of the packets, including the first one. Checking that `fcount > -1` assures that there *is* an open file to write to.

Comment: So you write each packet with first 3 char as defined and 4th containing the bits from 0xe0 (3 most significant bits set to 1 ) ?

Comment: @PtitXav Yes ..

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the catch, It works perfectly now!